# Configure snmp for orion

Tags: snmp

I have installed orion. But when it finds win7 nodes it doesn't recognize them as win7 via snmp, it recognizes them unknown.

I should say that I have installed and configured snmp and its trap.
But it doesn't work. Now I want to know, how should I configure snmp on win7 so that Orion snmp connects and gets information?

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable SNMP  in win7 "windows features".

You can check it by this steps.

Control Panel --> Programs and Features -->(On the right side ther should be) Turn Windows features on or off.

Enable SNMP and use WMI sensor to get more information about your node.

Hope, it'll helps..